# Nuxt how to debug: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

So in my Nuxt *universal-mode* app, I sometimes have an error which rises:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

Which usually comes along a second one (actually the second one sometimes rises without the first, not the other way round):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at emptyNodeAt (vue.runtime.esm.js:5851)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js:6492)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js:3933)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4048)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:4467)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js:4456)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4061)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js:8399)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js:3115)
    at hydrate (vue.runtime.esm.js:6362)
```

And then nothing works, since when I click to another page in my app, I get:

```
client.js:134 TypeError: Cannot read property '_transitionClasses' of undefined
    at Array.updateClass (vue.runtime.esm.js:6799)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:6298)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js:6177)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:6303)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js:6177)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:6303)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js:6177)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:6303)
    at updateChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js:6177)
    at patchVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js:6303)
```

I mostly understand the *why* this happens, though when it comes, I have no idea where to start from, since the error message doesn't give a single hint on what **actually are** the differences between the server-side version and the client one.

So when this issue rises, the only thing I can do is to rollback to previous git commits until the issues fixes itself ... which unfortunately doesn't work very well, as sometimes the bug appears on code versions where it was not there previously.

Usually the solution is to delete as many things as possible (`.nuxt`, `node_install`) and to set up everything from scratch and hopefully it works again.

Finally my remarks/questions are:

- When the `client-side version doesn't match the server-side` bug appears, why can't we have more detailed informations on **what differences**?
- Any idea why this bug happens as a whole in such non-deterministic manner?
- Why is this breaking everything, while at first this is simply a warning?

As for me this is a very big issue for a production app, as being so undeterministically fixable.

Comment: I've found that this can happen due to any invalid HTML syntax or structure on the page, not necessarily just in the component that's not matching. For example, placing a <form> inside of a <form> caused an extra #text element on server-side and was forcing hydration bail in a hard-to-trace manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in my case, the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error was rising at error-reporting time.

I happened to have the `The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content` warning in another context, I did receive useful explanations and it did not block execution so I shall consider the bug-over-the-bug was bad luck and would eventually get naturally fixed, unless it reproduces in the future.

If you happen to have the same error, **do not despair**.

First, report the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error to the nuxt repo.

Then, to debug, I encourage you to comment parts of your templates to find how to remove the error. In my case, it was in the layout, hence it happened **all the time**, but once I understood that, I found the explanation quite quickly (though it was a mysterious different behavior of `date-fns` between node environment and browser).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  Commenting out worked for me (I had an a tag inside a nuxt-link tag).